# Form Submit does nothing when i click on Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i have a form i created to save an audio file and its corresponding controllers (SoundController) and routes .
the problem is all the routes to display the views in the controller works perfectly but i can't seem or nothing happens when i click on the submit button. it just acts like the page is refreshed

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Sound;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SoundController extends Controller
{
    public function AllSound(){
        $sounds = Sound::latest()->get();
        return view('admin.all_sound',compact('sounds'));
    } // end function

    public function AddSound(){
        return view('admin.add_sound');
    } // end function


    public function StoreSound(Request $request){

        // validation
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|max:200',
            'so_file' => 'required',
            'caty' => 'required'
        ]);

        
            $file = $request->file("so_file");
            $filename = date('YmdHi').$file->getClientOriginalName();
            $move = $file->move(public_path('upload/sound_files/'),$filename);
            

           if($move){
            $sound = new Sound();
            $sound->name = $request->input('so_name');
            $sound->type = $request->input('caty');
            $sound->music = $filename;

            $sound->save();
            $notification = array(
                'message' => 'Sound saved Successfully',
                'alert-type' => 'success'
            );
            return redirect()->route('all.sound')->with($notification);
           }else{
            $notification = array(
                'message' => 'Sound not moved !',
                'alert-type' => 'error'
            );
            return redirect()->route('all.sound')->with($notification);
           }

        
    } // end function
}
```

these are my routes. it is the storeSound that saves it in the database.

```
Route::get('/admin/all/sounds', [SoundController::class, 'AllSound'])->name('all.sound');
    Route::get('/admin/add/sounds', [SoundController::class, 'AddSound'])->name('add.sound');
    Route::get('/edit/sound/{id}',[SoundController::class, 'EditSound'])->name('edit.sound');
    Route::get('/delete/sound/{id}',[SoundController::class, 'DeleteSound'])->name('delete.sound');
    Route::post('/store/sound',[SoundController::class, 'StoreSound'])->name('store.sound');
```

i tried checking every errors in the console or wherever but nothing shows the page is just like refreshed but strangely enough all the my other post in other controllers work perfectly
this is my form to add an audio. my php version is 8.1.13 and laravel version 10

```
<form class="forms-sample" action="{{ route('store.sound') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                            @csrf

                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="so_name" class="form-label">Name</label>
                                <input type="text" name="so_name" class="form-control 
                                @error('so_name') is-invalid @enderror">
                            
                           @error('so_name')
                            <span class="text-danger"> {{ $message }} </span>
                           @enderror
                           
                           
                            </div>
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="caty" class="form-label">Type</label>
                                <select name="caty">
                                    <option value="asmr">ASMR</option>
                                    <option value="whiteNoise">White Noise</option>
                                    <option value="sleep">Sleep</option>
                                    <option value="nature">Nature</option>
                                    <option value="instru">Instrumentals</option>
                                </select>
                            
                           @error('caty')
                            <span class="text-danger"> {{ $message }} </span>
                           @enderror
                           
                           
                            </div>
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="so_file" class="form-label">Sound File</label>
                                <input type="file" name="so_file" class="form-control 
                                @error('so_file') is-invalid @enderror">
                            
                           @error('so_file')
                            <span class="text-danger"> {{ $message }} </span>
                           @enderror
                           
                           
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary me-2">Save changes</button>
                            
                        </form>
```

Comment: What debugging have you done?  Check the network tab of your browser devtools - does the POST actually happen?  With the expected payload? What is the server response?  My guess is your validation is failing, but you forgot to display validation errors.

Answer (score 2):

this is due to **validation error**.. add this code in above of you form then see which error you face

```
    @if($errors->has())
    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
        <div>{{ $error }}</div>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: thanks guys for guiding me ! it was actually a validation problem. the thing is in my validation code i checked for a variable that was not even existing